# What is this stepped gradient effect called?

Tags: gradient, effects, style-identification, blur

I saw this effect of concentric circles discretely fading out (background of the image one).

I thought this was a circular gradient (radial-gradient).

But other images didn't seem to have a similar effect when I [searched the term](https://www.google.com/search?q=circular%20gradient&tbm=isch).

[image: Flutter Logo]

And another similar image that I saw uses the same kind of effect but it is not circular.

[image: Image 2]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Then I thought the effect I'm looking for was discrete color gradient.
Which lead me to [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=scale%20gradient&tbm=isch).

Is there a standard name for this kind of effect?

Comment: you're not asking about the gradient, you're asking about the "banding" effect in both these gradients, right? Because you already know the second one is not a radial blur, and the colors are not so discretely fading out, there are these "steps" between colors. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to know. The effect on the background which you're referring to as the "banding" effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd normally call it an undesirable artefact caused by high data compression or low bit-rate [see [colour banding]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding), but try '[posterisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization)' for an intentional method..

The first one I'm sure is unintentional colour banding, the second looks like true posterisation.